# Can you group generic objects into a list?

Tags: c#, generics

I have made a machine that converts biscuits from one type to another.

Each BiscuitTransformer has a method like the DigestiveBiscuitTransformer:

`IBiscuit Transform(DigestiveBiscuit digestiveBiscuit)` method.

Is it possible to group these using a common interface, given that the type will be different in each transformer, e.g. the ChocolateBiscuitTransformer

`IBiscuit Transform(ChocolateBiscuit chocolateBiscuit)`

The GingerNutBiscuitTransformer:

`IBiscuit Transform(GingerNutBiscuit gingerNutBiscuit)`

Ideally, what I am trying to achieve, is a BiscuitTransformationManager that will take in any type of biscuit, and give you an IBiscuit back.

It would load all of the transformers into a `List<IBiscuitTransformer>`and then IBiscuitTransformer would also expose `Type InputBiscuitType {get;}` so you could compare it to your incoming biscuit type:

BiscuitTransformationManager:

```
IBiscuit Transform<T>(T biscuit)
{
    var transformer = LoadTransformers().Single(c => c.InputBiscuitType == typeof(T));

    return transformer.Transform(biscuit);
}
```

I don't think works because the Transformer would be expecting a concrete type, not T.

The problem is I can't figure out how to group them, and if I make the interface method `Transform<T>` I am not sure how to implement it, because T would always be a `DigestiveBiscuit` in the `DigestiveBiscuitTransformer` but the code would accept anything, which makes no sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I have made a machine that converts biscuits from one type to another." You should patent it.

Comment: I would, but it doesn't work yet...!

Comment: do all Biscuits implement IBiscuit to begin with?

Comment: Is `InputBiscuitType` a property on `IBiscuitTransformer`? It looks like you need to add a type parameter for the input biscuit type `IBiscuitTransformer<in T> { IBiscuit Transform(T biscuit); }` then create an unsafe wrapper which implements `IBiscuitTransformer<IBiscuit>` which throws when given an invalid biscuit type. Then your manager needs a list of `IBiscuitTransformer<IBiscuit>` containing instances of the wrapper.

Comment: Yes it is, just so you can identify which transformer to use based on the type of supplied biscuit. I will try to understand the other things you have written and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need generics here.

How about simply this:

```
IBiscuit Transform(IBiscuit biscuit)
{
    var transformer = LoadTransformers().Single(c => c.InputBiscuitType == biscuit.GetType());

    return transformer.Transform(biscuit);
}
```

But, of course, this means that each of your transformers should have matching method signatures instead of being type specific, which I think is actually the correct way to go.

So instead of

```
IBiscuit Transform(DigestiveBiscuit digestiveBiscuit)
```

Change that transformer's signature (and the others as well) to:

```
IBiscuit Transform(IBiscuit digestiveBiscuit)
```

I think this design is cleaner and simpler than trying to make it work with generics.

Comment: Same comment as above, the reason for each transformer taking in a concrete type is that it has to access specific properties of that type, so you'd have to cast your IBiscuit to a DigestiveBiscuit on the first line of the DigestiveBiscuitTransformer to be able to access its properties to do the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can group the all type of biscuit to convert it in `BiscuitTransformManager`.

```
public interface ITransformedBiscuit {}

public class DigestiveBiscuit : ITransformedBiscuit {}

public class ChocolateBiscuit : ITransformedBiscuit {}

public class BiscuitTransformManager 
{
    IBiscuit Transform(ITransformedBiscuit biscuit)
    {
        // Use a reflection in here 
        var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where typeof(ITransformedBiscuit).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                     && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
            select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ITransformedBiscuit;

        foreach (var instance in instances)
        {
            instance.Transform(biscuit)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great, but the transformers have to know the specific type of biscuit, so on the first line of say, the `DigestiveBiscuitTransformer` you'd have to do `DigestiveBiscuit biscuit = (DigestiveBiscuit)ITransformedBiscuit` so you're specifying `IBiscuit` but the method will only work with `DigestiveBiscuit`, and I hoped there was a way to make it a bit safer/nicer in that way.